# Finding data for a determined week

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a table and I have a date in cell B4 which is something like 15/03/2021

I want to count values where the start date is the value on cell B4 but also count everything till the end of that week. So everything from Monday 15/03/2021 to Sunday 21/03/2021

What I have so far is something like

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,"Y",MySheet!C:C,">="&B4)
```

My trouble is how to tell it "also count everything until sunday that week without having to manually put the end date into a cell

Comment: That last double-quote shouldn't be there.  Also, will the start date **always** be a Monday, or might you start on Thursday? (and, if so, should it still count to Sunday, rather than to the next Wednesday)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add 6 to the value in B4 to get the second criteria.

```
=COUNTIFS(Mysheet!A:A,"Y",Mysheet!C:C,">="&B4, Mysheet!C:C,"<="&B4+6)
```

Answer (score 2):

I assume the question behind your question is how to account for dates in `B4` other than a monday and keep counting untill the end of that same week, therefor you can use:

```
=COUNTIFS(Mysheet!A:A,"Y",Mysheet!C:C,">="&B4,Mysheet!C:C,"<="&B4+7-WEEKDAY(B4,2))
```

This does set a Sunday as the "end" of the week as per your OP.

Answer (score 1):

Your question is slightly ambiguous, so there are two possible answers

To count for exactly 7 days:

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,"Y", MySheet!C:C,">="&B4, MySheet!C:C,"<"&B4+7)
```

To count until the end of the next Sunday:  (N.B. On Sundays, this will only count 1 day)

```
=COUNTIFS(MySheet!A:A,"Y", MySheet!C:C,">="&B4, MySheet!C:C,"<"&B4+8-Weekday(B4,2))
```

This works by saying "on or after (`>=`) the date given", and "**before** (`<`) 7 days later / the following Monday"